# OpenERP - how to update view with list values from py code

Tags: python, xml, odoo

In my py code I obtained list product_complete, which is list of strings. Function action_search is from a button "Search". I am wondering how I can update a view element (and what that element can be, like tree or something else?) with the values from my list from within Python code? Thanks.

Here is the code:

```
class mrp_bom(osv.Model):
    _inherit = 'mrp.bom'

    def action_search(self, cr, uid, ids, vals, context=None):
        bom_ids = []
        pd_ids = []
        product_complete = []
        ptemplid = int(self.browse(cr, uid, ids[0], context=context).product_tmpl_id.id)
        mbl_obj = self.pool.get('mrp.bom.line')
        id_s = mbl_obj.search(cr, uid,  [('product_id', '=', ptemplid)])
        for rec in mbl_obj.browse(cr, uid, id_s, context=context):    
            bom_ids.append(rec.bom_id.id) 
        for rec in self.browse(cr, uid, bom_ids, context=context):    
            pd_ids.append(rec.product_id.id)
        pp_obj = self.pool.get('product.product')
        for rec in pp_obj.browse(cr, uid, pd_ids, context=context):    
            product_complete.append('['+ str(rec.default_code) + ']'+ ' ' + str(rec.name_template))
        print "\n\n Inside action_search() product_complete ", product_complete
        # raise osv.except_osv(('Message!'), ('Inside action_search!' ) )
        vals = {'product_id' : product_complete}
        return {'value' : vals}
```

Here is my xml:

```
<record id="bom_where_use_form" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="name">bom.where.use.form</field>
            <field name="model">mrp.bom</field>
            <field name="priority" eval="20"/>
            <field name="type">form</field>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <field name="product_tmpl_id" > </field>
                <button name="action_search" string="Search" type="object" class="oe_highlight"/>
                <field name="bom_line_ids" widget="one2many_list">
                    <tree string="Components" editable="bottom">
                        <field name="sequence" widget="handle"/>
                        <field name="product_id" />
                    </tree>
                </field>
                <field name="product_id" /> 
            </field> 
        </record>
```

Comment: Can You please post you code.?

Comment: I have posted the code in the question.

Comment: Thanks, Andrei. At the end of the function I have a list of strings called product_complete, each string representing a full product code and name. Can you please be more specific, maybe with some example what you had in mind?

Comment: I need somehow to display list values from py code (list is product_complete) in the view.

Answer (score 0):

Your `return` statement should be something like this:

```
return {'value': {'field_name': field_value}}
```

In your code you are trying to assign list value to a simple field which is the id of a product.

I suppose you want to update some one2many field. For one2many and many2many values you may want to read the end of this document: https://doc.odoo.com/v6.0/developer/2_5_Objects_Fields_Methods/methods.html/

Comment: Thanks, Andrei. I have updated code in the question and added my xml. At the end of the function I have a list of strings called product_complete, each string representing a full product code and name. Can you please be more specific, maybe with some example what you had in mind? I used product_id but it is showing blank, I must be doing something wrong.

Comment: Why are you attempting to assign a list to a many2one relational field? mrp.bom.product_id is a reference to product.product - in this field you can store a single value which is the id of some product...